# Which is more performant: entity_metadata_wrapper or field_get_items?

Tags: performance, entities

To get values from entities, there are two ways:

- Use `field_get_items` and get the value of a field
- Use `entity_metadata_wrapper` and get the value of a field

Although `entity_metadata_wrapper` abstracts away the language differences, its API is still awkward sometimes, especially when using PHP 5.3. For example, getting the value of a long text field usually goes this route:

```
$field = $wrapper->field->value();
print $field['safe_value'];
```

Fortunately, PHP 5.4 supports this syntax: `print $wrapper->field->value()['safe_value'];`.

But my question is more concerned about performance. How do they both work? Do they query the database every time they request a value? Does `entity_metadata_wrapper` requests everything at once? (Making `field_get_item` more suited to single-value-retrievals.)

I'm not brave enough to dive deep into Drupal source.

Comment: `field_view_field()` is for rendering a field. The function to get the value of a field is [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_value/7).

Comment: And `field_get_items()` incurs zero database overhead so I think that's a pretty open and shut case :)

Comment: @Clive how come `field_get_items()` incurs zero database overhead? It has to get its data somewhere, right?

Comment: Also, I'm really interested in knowing how `entity_metadata_wrapper` works, performance-wise.

Comment: You pass a fully loaded entity object into `field_get_items()` so the overhead has already been incurred...it's a bit of a strangled route in D7 to be honest

Comment: I am using entity_metadata_wrapper for settings a lot of fields values. So it's is better in this case, because of code readability.

Comment: I do not buy the idea that entity_metadata_wrapper would be preferable for DX. The return type of $emw->field_xyz->value() is unpredictable from just looking at the code, and depends on the field instance configuration (e.g. single-value vs multiple-value vs entityreference). field_get_items() always has the same return type. it also does not throw exceptions (unless the entity is malformed).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The short answer: field_get_items() is more performant than entity_metadata_wrapper().**

Check out the code for these functions:

- [field_get_items()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7)
- [entity_metadata_wrapper()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.module/function/entity_metadata_wrapper/7)

Both require that you pass along the entity, ***which has already been loaded from the database***. For example:

```
$node = node_load(123);
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_field_name');
print $items[0]['value'];
```

or, as you've already suggested:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
$field = $wrapper->field_my_field_name->value();
print $field['safe_value'];
```

Both of these instances kind of bother me because of the silly logic in trying to get a value that's already available to you, but they are certainly useful in lots of cases.

You could just do `print $node->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];` but that would throw PHP notice errors if the field doesn't have a value, since you're trying to access arrays that may not exist (i.e. `[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']`). I find myself doing this quite often lately:

```
if ($field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_my_field_name')) {
  print $field[0]['value'];
}
```

which is a lot cleaner than doing:

```
if (isset($node->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE]) && isset($node->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0])) {
  print $node->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
}
```

If you look at the code for `field_get_items())` you'll see that it's doing nothing more then ensuring that the field's array has data in the curent language and then returns it. So, the overhead of running such a tiny function is negligible, but if you are really concerned with performance you can just do your own check if the data exists and then print it.

**Edit:** Since `field_get_items()` runs [`field_language()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.multilingual.inc/function/field_language/7) there would actually be a bigger performance hit than just checking the language, so, if you already know that $entity->language exists, you could just write your own super-performant function:

```
function my_super_performant_field_value_getter($entity, $field_name) {
  return isset($entity->{$field_name}[{$entity->language}]) ? $entity->{$field_name}[{$entity->language}] : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so apart from those checks, the entity is loaded once, no matter how many times I use them? Even if I use entity references?

Comment: Yes, this is actually a pretty cool feature of the entity API in D7. Once you load an entity, it is cached for the duration of that request. So, if you do `$node = node_load(123);` in 1 script and do that again elsewhere, you don't incur the performance overhead of a full object load and build – Drupal just assigns that variable a copy of the existing entity. If you want to load a *new* copy, you need to pass `$reset = TRUE` to the entity load function. Also, see my edits regarding a super performant getter.

Comment: `if (isset($node->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE]) && isset($node->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0])) {` is not necessary, `isset($node->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]` is enough.

Comment: @chx I agree, but wouldn't it be `isset($node->field_my_field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE])`, since the language will not be set on an empty field? I think it's the delta/`[0]` that is redundant.

Comment: entity_metadata_wrapper() does NOT require you to pass the fully loaded entity.  You can instead pass the entity id, in which case it theoretically just loads fields as needed, and if getting one field, is therefore presumptively quicker since fewer JOINs are needed.   But does anyone have any benchmarks?

Comment: @GilesB, more database queries are most often not better than joins. Eager loading is an optimisation technique. But even saying that, I think your assumption is false and EntityMetadataWrapper is probably slower, but it's so much nicer to use. This is also micro optimisation OP don't have to think about when working with Drupal.